# How do I iterate over a Map<string, string>?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object of type: `Map<string, string>`:

```
const foo = new Map<string, string>();

// e.g. foo is one => "1", two => "2", three => "3" etc.
```

I know I can get all the keys using:

```
const keys = Object.keys(foo);
```

But when I try to get each corresponding value using:

```
keys.forEach(k => {const val = foo[k]});
```

I get the following error:

```
type Map<string, string> has no index signature.
```

I need to be able to iterate through each key val. Any idea?

**Update**:

I have to say that I am casting the result of a `json` received via an ajax call to a type of `Map<string, string>` e.g. given the following json returned by an api call:

```
{
    one: "1",
    two: "2",
    three: "3"
}
```

I am then doing the following:

```
const response = await this.axios.get<Map<string, string>>("some/api");
const foo = response.data;
```

Comment: You can directly iterate a map `foo.forEach((value, key) => { ... })` Also for map you need to get the value using `.get` function `foo.get(k)`

Comment: Check the documentation for [`Map.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach)

Comment: @PSL None of those work, I am getting `foo.forEach` and `foo.get` is not a function. Please see the update.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? If so, please provide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question does not show an attempt to use `foo.forEach()`, but it *does* try to use `keys.forEach()`. `const keys = Object.keys(foo)` does *not* obtain the keys of a `foo: Map<string, string>`, but it will almost certainly return an empty `string[]`.

To get the `keys` of a `Map<string, string>` and iterate over them, you can do this:

```
for (const key of foo.keys()) {
  // each key of foo
}
```

or

```
Array.from(foo.keys()).forEach(key => {
  // each key of foo
})
```

Also, `axios` never returns a `Map<string, string>`, you probably meant `Object`, based on your usage, or you can use a more specialized type like `type Dictionary<T> = { [K: string]: T }` and

```
const response = await this.axios.get<Dictionary<string>>("some/api");
const foo = response.data
const keys = Object.keys(foo)

keys.forEach(key => { ... })
```

Comment: Aha! Excellent! That `Dictionary<T>` was exactly what I was missing. Works great now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When using [`Map.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach): first parameter is the value, the second is the key. No `.get` call is needed unless you use the 3rd parameter, which would be the map itself.

```js
const foo = new Map();

foo.set('foo', 'bar');
foo.set('bar', 'foo');

foo.forEach(function(v, k, fooMap){
  console.log(`map key: ${k}, map value: ${v}, fooMap: ${fooMap.get(k)}`);
})
```

Comment: Please see my comments above, that does not work for me.